# Ender 3 Printer not printing @ center for reasons unknown

Tags: creality-ender-3

I know this issue has been asked countless times before, but I haven't been able to fix my specific Ender 3 printer. I have been looking virtually everywhere via Reddit and here for answers, but I really don't have a clue what's going on and how to fix it.

i got my printer a couple months ago but just started recently using it often. i managed to get it to print several things successfully, but after one specific print, my Ender 3 printer decided to "home" itself to the top left corner of the printer. normally my Ender 3 printer auto-homes to the bottom left corner. ever since that weird "homing" incident, my printer has been never printing things out correctly. here's what has been happening:

1. my prints are never in the center of the print bed anymore.
2. my printer would move its y-axis to move the test bed away from the front of the printer even though it already is. this causes the motor to stutter and the entire bed to not move.
3. my printer would start extruding material on the very edge of the bed.

i believe what's happening is that the printer believes that the bed is somewhere where it actually isn't. my printer for the most part knew that it was always "centered" at the bottom left of the print bed, but now it seems as though it thinks that it is now centered at the top left corner.

i hope this all makes sense; i've been looking into several solutions but really am worried that those solutions won't work out for me. i appreciate all help and advice. i am a complete noob to 3d printing and am really stuck. thanks in advance!

Comment: Connect it to a PC and send the "M119" command - this will give you the current readings of the endstops. Are those normal?

Do all axes move in the right directions when commanded to?

Comment: i have tried connecting it to a PC several times now, but it seems that my computer and Cura doesn't detect the printer. I'm not sure if it is an issue with my printer itself with a faulty port or if the USB is just old. any suggestions?

Comment: Did it work before? You may need to install CH340G drivers for it to be recognized. Does anything appear in the Device Manager when you connect to the board?